# Simulating drag and drop with applescript

Tags: applescript

How can I simulate drag and drop with applescript? I'm creating a script that finds the newest image in the screenshot folder and drag and drops it to the slack window so it gets sent to the person I'm having a conversation with.

Comment: AS can't drag files. You'll have to use one of several available api's to send the file to slack. Stuff like:  do shell script "curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={…

Comment: @jweaks what are these guys talking about here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5991137?tstart=0

Comment: They're reaching in the dark. You can have an app open a file. That won't achieve what you're wanting. You'll have to use an api. You can have a folder action attached to the script, but that means you physically dragging a file, which you're wanting to avoid.

Comment: @unska I'm not familiar with Slack.  Can you paste files from your clipboard into a slack window? I'm thinking a good solution may be creating an AppleScript which will copy the newest screenshot file to your clipboard then pasting the clip board to the slack window

Comment: @wch1zpink copy paste actually worked. I only had to send enter after it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> @unska I'm not familiar with Slack. Can you paste files from your clipboard into a slack window? I'm thinking a good solution may be creating an AppleScript which will copy the newest screenshot file to your clipboard then pasting the clip board to the slack window – wch1zpink yesterday
>   @wch1zpink copy paste actually worked. I only had to send enter after it. Thank you! – unska 16 hours ago

I wrote this script which will take a screenshot, then copy it to your clipboard then that it will activate Slack and paste the screenshot into your message and send it.

```
do shell script "screencapture -c" -- This takes a screencapture and copies it to the clipboard.  

    -- Below, I added the different usage examples for screencapture right from the man page in Terminal

    (*
    usage: screencapture [-icMPmwsWxSCUtoa] [files]
      -c         force screen capture to go to the clipboard
      -b         capture Touch Bar - non-interactive modes only
      -C         capture the cursor as well as the screen. only in non-  interactive modes
      -d         display errors to the user graphically
      -i         capture screen interactively, by selection or window
               control key - causes screen shot to go to clipboard
               space key   - toggle between mouse selection and
                             window selection modes
               escape key  - cancels interactive screen shot
      -m         only capture the main monitor, undefined if -i is set
      -M         screen capture output will go to a new Mail message
      -o         in window capture mode, do not capture the shadow of the window
      -P         screen capture output will open in Preview
      -I         screen capture output will in a new Messages message
      -s         only allow mouse selection mode
      -S         in window capture mode, capture the screen not the window
      -t<format> image format to create, default is png (other options include pdf, jpg, tiff and other formats)
      -T<seconds> Take the picture after a delay of <seconds>, default is 5
      -w         only allow window selection mode
      -W         start interaction in window selection mode
      -x         do not play sounds
      -a         do not include windows attached to selected windows
      -r         do not add dpi meta data to image
      -l<windowid> capture this windowsid
      -R<x,y,w,h> capture screen rect
      -B<bundleid> screen capture output will open in app with bundleidBS
  files   where to save the screen capture, 1 file per screen
    *)

    delay 2
tell application "Slack"
    activate

    delay 5 -- this gives you time to put your cursor in the window where you want to paste your screencapture.  This was the only option I could think of because I do not have Slack so I do not know any of the UI elements or window names as to where to tell this script where to place the screencapture.

        tell application "System Events"
            key code 9 -- this will paste the screencapture from your clipboard into the active Slack window where your cursor is.
            delay 1
            key code 36 -- this should press the return key and send your message
        end tell
end tell
```

---

In script editor, save this script as an application. Then you can make the application speakable and launch it with dictation commands and configure it to launch with a keyboard shortcut.  You could also just run the application as it is.